# Viewbag , Printing data from hashset

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hashset, viewbag

i want to print the viewbag recieved from the controller but i cant, my code in the controller is here:

```
var qry = from c in db.Customers
          join o in db.Orders on id equals o.CustomerID
          where id == o.CustomerID
          select new {o.OrderID ,o.OrderDetails};
ViewBag.OrdersForUser = qry.ToList();
```

the printing code in my view is :

```
@foreach (var order in ViewBag.OrdersForUser)
{
   @order
}
```

the printed text right now is:

```
{ OrderID = 1, OrderDetails = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[FinalProject.Models.OrderDetail] }
```

the type of OrderID is int, the type of OrderDeatils is ICollection
i want to print the data in the hash set (and not the decleration like now) , and to split the Order Id into other space.

Comment: `OrdersForUser` is a collection of anonymous objects which are internal and can't be access in the view. Create a view model with the 2 properties for `OrderID` and  `OrderDetails` and populate it - `select new yourModel { .... }` and return that to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBag is a dynamic type. And you assign an anonymous type, then you cant get its type in view side.

**controller**

```
var qry = from c in db.Customers
      join o in db.Orders on id equals o.CustomerID
      where id == o.CustomerID
      // in this line, what is the type of list ? You should define its type
      // for example:
      select new SomeType{OrderId = o.OrderID ,OrderDetails = o.OrderDetails}
      //select new {o.OrderID ,o.OrderDetails}; 

ViewBag.OrdersForUser = qry.ToList();
```

and then in your

**view**

```
@foreach (var order in (List<SomeType>)ViewBag.OrdersForUser)
{
   @order
}
```

- List that you return from controller, should not be anonymous type. (select new SomeType)
- In view, you should define viewbag type. (List)ViewBag.OrdersForUser)

---

**AFTER COMMENT**

Or if there is relation definitions between your entities, you can get only order details like following :

**controller:**

```
ViewBag.OrdersForUser = db.OrderDetails.Where(d=>d.Order.CustomerId == id);
```

**view :**

```
@foreach (var orderDetail in (List<OrderDetail>)ViewBag.OrdersForUser)
{
   @orderDetail.Order.xxx
}
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType5`1[System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[FinalProject.Models.OrderDetail]]]'

Comment: the o.OrderDetails var is ICollection<OrderDetail>, i want it to be printing and the error is becuase i cannot cast it, i tried both:  foreach (var order in (List<string>)ViewBag.OrdersForUser)
            {
            order
            
            } ... and also cast to OrderDetail list

Comment: You should define a class something like this class CustomerOrder{int OrderId, List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails}

Comment: i created the class, i got the same error:my code is:     foreach (var order in (List<FinalProject.Models.CustomerOrder>)ViewBag.OrdersForUser) .... and the error is Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType5`2[System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[FinalProject.Models.OrderDetail]]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FinalProject.Models.CustomerOrder]'.

Comment: view part : foreach (var order in (List<FinalProject.Models.CustomerOrder>)ViewBag.OrdersForUser)
            {
            order
            }

Comment: controller part: public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);

            var qry = from c in db.Customers
                      join o in db.Orders on id equals o.CustomerID
                      where id == o.CustomerID
                      select new CustomerOrder { OrderID = o.OrderID, OrderDetails = o.OrderDetails };
            ViewBag.OrdersForUser = qry.ToList() ;
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

Comment: the new class:   public class CustomerOrder
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }


    }